# WSO2-IS - Giving "Invalid Code" after reset password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to create a password to a new user created on WSO2-IS 5.11.0 using the link sent by email, but I'm facing an error after click on Proceed:

[image: Invalid Code]

In the log it doesn't show anything

Version: 5.11.0

Comment: can you add the enabled configs and tried out flow in step by step? Also, mention the browser URL that you will be ended up when the above error is shown (mask if there any sensitive values in query params)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a **proxy_cookie_path** attribute on NGinx to make cookies be sent on cross-site requests. By default WSO2 products use “Double Submit Cookie" and "Synchronize Token Pattern” to prevent CSRF attacks.

nginx.conf

```
location /is/ {
            proxy_pass  https://csm-wso2-is:9444/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_redirect https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/oauth2/ https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/is/oauth2/;
            proxy_redirect https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/carbon/ https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/is/carbon/;
            proxy_redirect https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/authenticationendpoint/ https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/is/authenticationendpoint/;
            proxy_redirect https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/accountrecoveryendpoint/ https://dev-web-mtz.close-upinternational.com/is/accountrecoveryendpoint/;

            # Proxy headers
            proxy_set_header Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection         "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
            #Proxy headers

            # Proxy timeouts
            proxy_send_timeout                 5m;
            proxy_read_timeout                 5m;
            proxy_cookie_path / "/; SameSite=None";
        }
```

According to WSO2 documentation: [SameSite Attribute Support in WSO2 Products](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/administer/samesite-attribute-support/#samesite-attribute-in-wso2-identity-server)

Answer (score 1):

When you get the mail check the password recovery link that you have received. There are two ways that you can find the link.

- You can copy the link by right-clicking on the button.
- Recovery link at the bottom of the page.

You should see a recovery link as below.

```
https://localhost:9443/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmrecovery.do?confirmation=ea626c2f-47f7-4184-b927-5f230686716c&userstoredomain=PRIMARY&username=sominda&tenantdomain=carbon.super&callback=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2Fauthenticationendpoint%2Flogin.do%3Fclient_id%3DMY_ACCOUNT%26code_challenge%3Dmiilh2DN9GCQwLQVBn8s99fc2_D9Q8YoCAFX7GA4dLs%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26commonAuthCallerPath%3D%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%26forceAuth%3Dfalse%26passiveAuth%3Dfalse%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2Fmyaccount%2Flogin%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3DSYSTEM+openid%26tenantDomain%3Dcarbon.super%26sessionDataKey%3D1ca27665-1d5c-41f6-9e3e-e320139e2b94%26relyingParty%3DMY_ACCOUNT%26type%3Doidc%26sp%3DMy+Account%26isSaaSApp%3Dtrue%26authenticators%3DBasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL
```

Check the value for the `confirmation` param. According to what you have recieved the its value should be `%s`. This means that the recovery code is not properly set in the email.

The reason for this can be an error when updating the email template. The email template for password recovery should contain a placeholder for `confirmation`. Make sure the placeholder is as follows.

```
confirmation={{confirmation-code}}
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: My problem is with reverse proxy, but I don't know why yet. If I use an url without proxy it works, but if I use a proxy don't.

Comment: Most probably your reverse proxy is not passing an essential header when requesting the recovery code. Will you able to check the difference in HTTP(S) headers via reverse proxy and without reverse proxy. Especially look for "Host", "Referer" headers.

Comment: @RuwanAbeykoon the only difference is that `Keep-Alive: timeout=60` is not been passed when I'm using reverse proxy. Is there any example of IS with NGinx Reverse Proxy?